# Multiply even-indexed elements of array by 2 and odd-indexed elements of array by 3?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I have the following array which contains all numbers from 1 to 10:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I want to multiply every even-indexed element by 2 and every odd-indexed element by 3. I want my array to look like:

```
[2,6,6,12,10,18,14,24,18,30]
```

I tried the following solution:

```
numbers.select do |x|
  if x.even?
    x * 2
  else
    x * 3
  end
  puts x
end
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work. Does anyone have any better methods?

Comment: In future, I suggest you wait awhile before selecting your preferred answer.  A rush to judgement discourages other, possibly better, answers and in my opinion is a discourtesy to those still preparing answers when the green checkmark appears.  @Cerael had no business pressuring you to select his or her answer a mere seven minutes after you posted the question.  In case you are unaware, you can always change your choice of preferred answer.

Comment: Your solution is quite close.  First, remove `puts x`, as `x` has not been modified by `x * 2` or `x * 3`.  To print the results,  change `select` to `each` and write `puts (if x.even?...end)`.  To save the results, change `select` to `map`.  Your statement of the question is unambiguous, though you should not have made `numbers` a sequence, as it evidently caused some confusion.  Something like `numbers = [6, 5, 8, 2]` would have been better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you want every even *index* to be multiplied by 2, and odd indices by 3.

This should do the trick

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
numbers.map!.with_index { |n, i| i.even? ? n * 2 : n * 3 }
p numbers
# => [2,6,6,12,10,18,14,24,18,30]
```

As for your attempt, `#select` *selects* elements from an Enumerator wherever the result of the block is true. When you want to modify an Enumerator in place, you should use `#map!`. The `#with_index` method is available to all Enumerators to include an index in your block.

Comment: If the asker has not selected an answer within several hours or perhaps a day of asking, it is reasonable to post a gentle reminder that the asker should select the most helpful answer, if there was at least one.  Asking that your answer be selected, and asking mere minutes of the question being posted, is not what SO is about.  Many of us would *never* reward such unprofessional behavior with an upvote.

Comment: I meant to say select *an* answer, since I see so many questions go unaccepted. I agree asking to select your own answer is inappropriate, I'll remove it.

Comment: Your first sentence is inconsistent with what you are doing, unless you are expecting `numbers` to be a sequence, in which case you don't need `with_index`.

Answer (score 3):

```
numbers.map.with_index { |n, i| n * (i.even? ? 2 : 3) }
=> [2, 6, 6, 12, 10, 18, 14, 24, 18, 30]
```

Comment: `n * (i.even? ? 2 : 3)`. Nice and clean. +1

Comment: +1 for a good, straightforward solution to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Your block doesn't a return x*2 or x*3 but the result of `puts x`. You need to remove this line for your block.

Comment: Technically, this is the only answer that addressed the OPs problem.

Comment: Merely removing `puts x`, without changing `select` to `map`, returns `numbers`.

Comment: I got confused between `collect` and `select`

Answer (score 0):

`Array#select` filters the array based on the evaluation of the code in the block. If the block returns a "truthy" value (anything that is not `false` or `nil`), the element is retained, otherwise it is discarded.

What you want is the `map` method. `map` returns a new array that is populated by the return of the block.

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10].map { |x| x.even? ? x * 2 : x * 3 }
```

Comment: sorry, what I meant was even and odd indexed elements.

Answer (score 0):

Golfing it a little:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
puts numbers.each_with_index.map{|n, i| n * (2 + i % 2) }
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, it would be best if you could provide a little explanation for why it does so.

Comment: Idan, this saves you 45 characters: `n=[*1..10];p n.map.with_index{|n,i|n*(2+i%2)}`

Comment: @PlasmaHH, I'm not sure the complexity of this answer warrants an explanation, but here is one: `enum = numbers.each_with_index.map
=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator:...:map>`.  To see what the enumerator `enum` will pass into its block: `enum.to_a
=> [[1, 0], [2, 1], [3, 2],...[10, 9]]`, the first being `n, i = [1, 0]`, so `n => 1`, `i => 0`, etc.

Comment: @PlasmaHH It's not **that** tricky. `each_with_index.map` is quite standard. Instead of checking for parity and using a conditional(`if` or `? :`) to decide how to multiply, I use `2 + i % 2`. `i % 2` will yield `0` for even indices and `1` for odd indices, and by adding `2` we get `2` for even indices and `3` for odd indices.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using [`cycle`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-cycle):

```
multiply_by = [2, 3].cycle
numbers.map { |n| n * multiply_by.next }
# => [2, 6, 6, 12, 10, 18, 14, 24, 18, 30]
```

Comment: You might want to check your work: `undefined method `next' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)` because `p` isn't defined.

Comment: @theTinMan - renamed the variable to be more readable... forgot to replace all... :-P fixed it, thanks

Comment: I make it a practice to copy the answer code directly from my editor (Sublime) or IRB so it's my actual working code just to avoid this sort of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution in JavaScript.

> function modifyArray(nums) {
>           return nums.map(num => num % 2 == 0 ? num * 2 : num * 3)
>       }